# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED after updating Python when trying to access results in IBM QE

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I had a question earlier about the Numpy DeprecationWarning flooding issue. I just updated the Python in my regular jupyter notebook and have trouble running the following cell:

```
cal_job = execute(cal_circuits, 
                 backend = backend,
                 shots = 1024,
                  optimization_level = 0
                 )
***cal_results = cal_job.result()***
meas_fitter = CompleteMeasFitter(cal_results, state_labels)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
meas_fitter.plot_calibration(ax)
```

My code worked fine before upgrading but now it shows the following error message (The line with the error is marked with***):

```
SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

On the IBMQ Experience page it shows my job has been successfully executed, but I cannot obtain any result from the notebook. What should I do? Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If running on MacOS, did you try to `Install Certificates`? You can execute the following line in a terminal, replacing `<version>` with your Python version.

```
/Applications/Python\ <version>/Install\ Certificates.command
```

Comment: Thanks, should I do that in my terminal?

Comment: Yeap. Answer updated to include that important detail.

Comment: That works, thanks so much!

Comment: Am I supposed to type the above line directly into terminal on Mac? This gives me an error